# Can't change target SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, target

I created a project in Android Studio, and want to change the target SDK.  When I navigate to the File | Project Structure | app Module | Flavors tab, the target SDK drop down only contains the version I specified at project creation - the same goes for the Min SDK Version.  Shouldn't I be able to pick a new version, or must I recreate the project?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK dropdown in Project Structure only contains SDK versions you have downloaded.

Comment: Odd.  It showed me every version when I initially created the project.

Comment: Because at that point it would download the version if it wasn't installed. I don't know why it's like this, but it is :/